# Typescript equivalent for functional compose for multiple nested generics

Tags: typescript, generics

Sometimes I do a lot of operations on a type in order to create a new one, ie:

```js
type Complex = Omit<Merge<Interface1, {modifiedField: false}>, 'omitted field'>
```

Is there any equivalent of a functional `compose` or `pipe` functions so that creating such a type would more readable, ie:

```js
type Complex = Pipe<Interface1, 
   Merge<{modified: false}>,
   Omit<'omitted field'>
>
```

Comment: It is not possible to partially apply type constructors, so IMOP not possible in TS in current level. You can only pass evaluated types and in your example you are for example applying right argument to `Omit` and right argument to `Merge`. You can pass only concrete types into generic arguments, type constructors cannot be passed. You can think more about some workaroud for some specific actions on type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the language doesn't have higher-order type manipulation of the kind needed for this to work.  The closest I can imagine is to drop from the type level to the value level, abuse the recent [support for higher order function inference from generic functions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), and then move back up to the type level.  It's not pretty and you end up with a little useless runtime code to boot.

Here's what I mean.  I'm assuming you have these definitions:

```
interface Interface1 {
    a: string;
    "omitted field": boolean;
}
type Merge<T, U> = T & U;
type ManualComplex = Omit<Merge<Interface1, { modifiedField: false }>, 'omitted field'>
/* type ManualComplex = {
    a: string;
    modifiedField: false;
} */
```

Then here's the hoop-jumping with values I'm talking about:

```
declare const CurriedOmit: <K extends PropertyKey>() => <T>(t: T) => Omit<T, K>;
declare const CurriedMerge: <U>() => <T>(t: T) => Merge<T, U>;
declare const Id: <T>() => T
```

I'm pretending that there's a curried `Omit` and `Merge`, as well as an `Id`.  Then we can pretend that there's a `pipe()` function that applies these in order:

```
// there may be some variadic pipe but for now let's do this:
declare const pipe: {
    <A>(a: A): A;
    <A, B>(a: A, b: (a: A) => B): B;
    <A, B, C>(a: A, b: (a: A) => B, c: (b: B) => C): C;
    <A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: (a: A) => B, c: (b: B) => C, d: (c: C) => D): D;
}
```

Finally I write some actual runtime code that fools the compiler into evaluating the type you want, although at runtime the code will short-circuit to `true` (which is good because if it were to actually call the non-existent `pipe()` function you'd get a runtime error):

```
const complex = (true as false) || pipe(
    Id<Interface1>(),
    CurriedMerge<{ modifiedField: false }>(),
    CurriedOmit<'omitted field'>()
);
```

Now that the compiler thinks it has a value `complex`, we can get `Complex` as `typeof complex`:

```
type Complex = typeof complex;
/* type Complex = {
    a: string;
    modifiedField: false;
} */
```

Is it the same type as `ManualComplex`? Yes. Is it worth it? No. I'd definitely stick with the non-piped version you started with.

[Playground Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJBGZBvAKGWOTgC5kBnMKUAcwG4iSAiAewFtgxIATZGMAgAbXiwoAjNm2EQ4IJgF8CYAJ4AHFAFlodCAB4AKgBpkAVQB8yALzJDyAGTmmazci3yArnGEBhTuqyAB42yADyXGD6OlB6+uiQsIgQ2KZ4yBxsvMCCELwAYkKiFPDClCiKFqYA5JzcfAJFvNUWBAD0AFTIrtpePv4cgRAhtoQkpBTUtCCMzMSZ2bkFTSU+5UrIHW0EBLwQCMJwUCgIbCDUyL6eULR5EdwU+gDSyMOQILyUyAAKUGyaUDUTwgqgsAAoAJQ2KxGcFgCiGKHWKz3KImZBPCxMPYHI4nM4XK43IS8GJ6R6WSHQ5CwsHwuxIqxkgzoyzY-aHY7IU7nMBoXiPQzgxl2dptboAC2gKA4cFUyAkKEonBQADcjsA4NkEMh1MA3BJPHyYGwoMgQGwAO7IWRgapfXhsSXAShkXYcvHcgl8vWaChjEj6ACC4PIyCDEIoQaY42DpgAQqGo6YJBQwWGI9T45HkPGY4GgwnTL4k+GU2mMyL46YEGnU7mRb4c7588Q47ni6YACKlwsKitRqs1usUbPU3ymAXIMG1y4irs5rtKAg8i6nQbBUJ0qCeFBwL6lcpQgA+x91+ogYLm-PiGCSOGFxmvRNupN0BnSCxyJMKIinh4qR9n2uV9UX0WpIgaXJRBaSECAhFwNBQAYhhGbokLYGAvQ3YYmE6dC3BQzdRmvMMpnoVsMiyb88l-YoBDWCANi2HYiFYgggA)